# Process files in loop with output from find

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, find

Perennial mutation of common question.

Disregarding find's -exec function and xargs, how do I process in a loop the output of a function that uses find?

The intent was to rely on a function to contain an oft-repeated find statement with many args. Ignoring also the [possibility of storing the args in an array](https://serverfault.com/a/707800/535094), how can I simply loop over the results of the oft-repeated find statement, having put it an a function?

A simple example:

```
function ftf ()
{
find . -type f -name "*" 2> /dev/null
}
```

The function finds these files when run in the /etc/cups dir.

```
._. ftf

./raw.types
./subscriptions.conf.O
./cupsd.conf
./subscriptions.conf
./raw.convs
./printers.conf
./cups-files.conf
./printers.conf.O
./snmp.conf
./cups-browsed.conf
```

But running `basename` over the results, makes it seems as though the loop is operating on only the last file.

```
._. for fp in "$(ftf "$1")"; do printf "%s\n" "$(basename "$fp")"; done

cups-browsed.conf
```

Just printing the files seems to work:

```
for fp in "$(ftf "$1")"; do printf "%s\n" "$fp"; done

./raw.types
./subscriptions.conf.O
./cupsd.conf
./subscriptions.conf
./raw.convs
./printers.conf
./cups-files.conf
./printers.conf.O
./snmp.conf
./cups-browsed.conf
```

But in fact it is only printing the whole output of find in one go:

```
._. for fp in "$(ftf "$1")"; do echo "new line!"; printf "%s\n" "$fp"; done

new line!
./raw.types
./subscriptions.conf.O
./cupsd.conf
./subscriptions.conf
./raw.convs
./printers.conf
./cups-files.conf
./printers.conf.O
./snmp.conf
./cups-browsed.conf
```

Notwithstanding that there are other ways of doing this, how do I simply loop over the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is addressed by https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.

Assuming your file names don't contain newlines:

```
while IFS= read -r fp; do
    printf '%s\n' "$fp"
done < <(ftf)
```

By the way, your function should be:

```
ftf() {
    find . -type f 2>/dev/null
}
```

As you don't need both `function` and `()` and the latter is more portable, and saying `-name "*"` means "any name" so you don't need to specify that, and I assume you're trying to redirect stderr but missed the `>`.

If your file names CAN contain newlines then:

```
ftf() {
    find . -type f -print0 2>/dev/null
}

while IFS= read -r -d '' fp; do
    printf '%s\0' "$fp"
done < <(ftf)
```

Comment: Close! But slightly off target. Your answer gives an ambiguous redirect error. But your reference (wooledge.org) has the solution -- don't redirect the command output into the loop, but pipe it: ftf | while IFS= read -r fp; do printf '%s\n' $(basename "$fp"); done

Comment: @markling while that's one workaround, it's not the best approach as it runs the loop in a subshell and then you don't have access to the variables set inside of it outside. I had just used a `$` instead of `<` in the command output redirection - fixed now. You don't need `basename` - if you just want the file name and not the whole path then just use `printf '%s\n' "${fp##*/}"`.

Comment: No error this time, but no results either. No files reported from the loop at all!

Comment: The code does what you asked for so my best guesses are that you copy/pasted it wrong, or you don't have any files under your directory, or you aren't using a shell like bash that supports `< <(command)`.

Comment: Yeah, it was too big for me to get my small brain round it.